# Cannot send google calendar event to non gmail calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api

Followed the below link 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java

working only for gmail calendar. How to send calendar event to non gmail accounts?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can send calendar invites even to non-gmail users. Just include their email in the `attendees[].email` array property. Don't forget to set sendNotifications to true to send notifications about the creation of the new event to the attendees. You can give this a try in the [Events.insert Try-it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).

If you've sent emails to non Gmail users and they haven't received it, it maybe that it was placed in spam folders as mentioned in 
[Event Invite for non-Google calendar users](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/csbN7Nre5gU).